# Find condition of X such that I-XSA is nonsingular, where $S$ is skew-symmetric and $A$ is symmetric, nonsingular

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Given $I_n$ is the identity matrix, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is symmetric and nonsingular, and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is skew-symmetric.\
a) For which condition of a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$, the matrix $I_n - XSA$ is nonsingular?
b) How should $X$ be computed such that the 2-norm of X be minimized?

I have found one condition for part a) but it seems not good enough. It is that a matrix $\begin{bmatrix} A^{-1} & X \\ S & I_n \end{bmatrix}$ is nonsingular. The proof is obtained by the fact that $\sigma(I_n-XSA) = \sigma(I_n-SAX)$ (where $\sigma(M)$ is the spectrum of a matrix $M$), and then used the Schur-complement.